# in_array не находит значение в массиве

Tags: php

Добрый день. Делаю вот такую простенькую штуку.

Есть запрос к БД

```
$resulta = mysql_query("SELECT time_priema FROM medical_tickets where doctor_name='$separator' and day_priema='$separatora' ORDER BY id DESC");

while ($postrowa[] = mysql_fetch_array($resulta))



if (in_array('10.40', $postrowa))
 {
 $disabled = 'disabled';
 }
 else
 {
 $disabled = NULL;
 }
```

Проще говоря, если в массиве встречается время `10.40`, то переменная `$disable` должна получить значение `disabled`, в противном случае `NULL`. Запрос к БД проходит, и выводит все группу нужных значений, среди которых и `10.40`. Вопрос, почему `in_array` не видит этого значения в массиве?

Описание функции брал [здесь](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php)

В общем, господа. Прихожу к выводу, что во всем виноват массив.
Если задать его прямо на странице вот таким образом, то все работает.

```
 $postrowa = array("09.20", "10.40");
```

Остается вопрос, почему из БД данные не проходят? Честно говоря, пока понять не могу.

Comment: Приведите пример данных в массиве, к примеру через var_dump($postrowa). И еще, как вы проверяете, что значение disabled получено не было?

Comment: Вот такую информацию выдает var_dump:

array(3) { 
[0]=> array(2) 
{ 
[0]=> string(5) "12.40" ["time_priema"]=> string(5) "12.40" 
} 
[1]=> array(2) 
{ 
[0]=> string(5) "09.20" ["time_priema"]=> string(5) "09.20" 
} 
[2]=> bool(false) 
}

Проверить можно хотя бы тем же echo.

Comment: @anj1817, так в этой *"информации"*, а именно в **результате**, нет искомого "10:40"

Comment: @HA3IK, я пытался разобраться. Подумал что может напутал где, что и сменил все время, после того как запостил вопрос. Проблема не в этом.

Comment: @anj1817, будет намного удобнее, если вы вернёте обратно в рабочее состояние (где есть именно искомое время) и добавите к вопросу ещё и выводимый результат из БД

Comment: @HA3IK, вернул значения.
array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "10.40" ["time_priema"]=> string(5) "10.40" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "09.20" ["time_priema"]=> string(5) "09.20" } [2]=> bool(false) }

В результате вывода данных из массива циклом for получаем два значения:
10.40 и 09.20.

Comment: @HA3IK, если поставить вместо  $disabled = NULL; допустим  $disabled = 1;  то выводится на странице 1. Тоесть всегда срабатывает else.

Comment: @anj1817, проблема в том, что в результате из БД, который Вы предоставили, "10.40" находится в ещё одном массиве.  **Т.е:** `in-array` находит только array-и, он не заходит внутрь подмассивов, чтобы увидеть нужный "10.40"

Comment: @HA3IK, как быть в таком случае? Что делать?

Comment: @anj1817, Для начала, Вы не указали какой тип возвращаемых данных должны вернуться из `mysql_fetch_array`, об этом подробнее здесь: https://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-array.php. Я бы вообще отказался от использования `mysql_fetch_array` и тому подобных устаревших методов обработки БД, - рекомендую **PDO**. После чего пересмотрите все fetch-методы и определите для себя **цель**: получить один, сплошной массив с результатами

Answer (score 3):

Лишние квадратные скобки в строке: while ($postrowa[] = mysql_fetch_array($resulta))

Answer (score 1):

Выведите результат из БД, с помощью:

```
print_r($postrowa) или var_dump($postrowa)
```

...и убедитесь, что "10:40" есть в результате вообще, и именно в искомом виде.
Также убедитесь, чтобы в результате, с "10:40", не было ничего кроме пробельных символов